# What is the relationship between minimum pitch effect and intensity?

Tags: phonetics

I am using relative intensity as a metric for the degree of lenition in voiced stops. Several other papers use this metric but report the minimum pitch: (Warner and Tucker 2011: 1609 & Carrasco, Hualde and Simonet 2012: 156) Why do you need to report the minimum pitch when working with intensity? How does minimum pitch affect intensity?

Thanks:

References.

Warner, N., & Tucker, B. V. (2011). Phonetic variability of stops and flaps in spontaneous and careful speech. The Journal of the Acoustical Society of America, 130(2009), 1606. doi:10.1121/1.3621306

Carrasco, P., Hualde, J. I., & Simonet, M. (2012). Dialectal Differences in Spanish Voiced Obstruent Allophony: Costa Rican versus Iberian Spanish. Phonetica, 69(3), 149–179.

Comment: It might help if you could translate your headline ("What is the relationship between minimum pitch affect intensity?") into correct English.

Comment: haha, it was a late one last night :)

Answer (score 1):

Observationally, RMS amplitude is positively correlated with F0. When F0 is high, the vocal folds have greater tension and they close more rapidly, which means that there is more force when they meet under high F0 compared to low F0. That greater force, when the vocal folds meet, translates into an increase in acoustic energy in the glottal waveform. That said, the real reason for reporting "minimum pitch" is that Praat uses the variable *minimum_pitch* to determine the size of the analysis window. A Praat intensity curve is much smoother than a raw RMS narrow-window computation, so there is a lot of stuff going on in the black box. You report all relevant experimental settings, e.g. sampling rate, bit-rate, and so on, since they affect the replicability of an experiment.